# Why variable changed after pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The related stub is like:

```
tag=('*' '#')
i=0
function output()
{
    ifs="$IFS"
    IFS=$'\n'
    for line in $@
    do
        echo $'\t' "${tag[$i]}" $line
    done
    IFS="$ifs"
    echo $i
    i=$((i+1))
    echo $i
    i=$((i%2))
    echo $i
}

output a|tee README
output b
```

What I want to do is:

Every time execute `output` to output a message block, different prefix(`${tag[$ind]}`) can be used for distinguishing itself from context. Besides, part-message can be redirect to file.

Result of it is:

```
         * a
    0
    1
    1
         * b
    0
    1
    1
```

With the pipe `|tee README`, variable `$i` had been reset to `0`.

Why it happened and can I implement the function by this train of thought?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens becase, as stated at [Bash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

In order to preserve `i` variable value I suggest you to enclose the two `output` calls into a single shell process as follow:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

tag=('*' '#')

i=0

function output()
{
    ifs="$IFS"
    IFS=$'\n'
    for line in $@
    do
        echo $'\t' "${tag[$i]}" $line
    done
    IFS="$ifs"
    echo $i
    i=$((i+1))
    echo $i
    i=$((i%2))
    echo $i
}

(
    output a
    output b
) | tee README
```

Comment: Please upvote if it solved. :)